# C# БД сохранение изменений в таблице используя gridView

Tags: c#, база-данных, .net, update

Загрузка таблицы происходит из access, отображаю его в gridView.

Сохранение:

```
        connection.Open();

        // перебор всех строк dataGridView и присваивание dataSet-у
        for (int i = 0; i < dataSetPlayerSkill.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < dataSetPlayerSkill.Tables[0].Rows[0].ItemArray.Length; j++)
                dataSetPlayerSkill.Tables[0].Rows[i].ItemArray[j] = dataGridViewPlayerSkill.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value;
        }
        dataSetPlayerSkill.AcceptChanges();

        adapter.SelectCommand = commandPlayerSkill;
        adapter.UpdateCommand = new OleDbCommand("UPDATE PlayerSkill SET [Поле1] = 3,[Поле2] = 3,[Поле3] = 3,[Поле4] = 3 WHERE [Код] = 1;", connection);
        adapter.Update(dataSetPlayerSkill);
        adapter.UpdateCommand = new OleDbCommand("UPDATE PlayerSkill SET [Поле1] = 3,[Поле2] = 3,[Поле3] = 3,[Поле4] = 3 WHERE [Код] = 2;", connection);
        adapter.Update(dataSetPlayerSkill);
        dataSetPlayerSkill.AcceptChanges();

        connection.Close();
```

Изменения сохраняются, если изменяется ячейка вручную(двойной клик по ячейки и ввод значения), но если ячейка изменяется программой( dataGridView2.Rows[0].Cells[j].Value = 2), то бд не сохраняет изменения

К тому же, сохраняется только 1 запрос(sql update), выше показан пример, что из двух и более update на разные строки сохраняется только первая строка

Объявления:

```
    string tableNamePlayerSkill;
    string tableNameMain;
    string dataBasePath;
    string dataBaseName;
    double[][] matrixFirst;
    double[][] matrixAlternativ;
    OleDbConnection connection;
    OleDbDataAdapter adapter;
    OleDbCommand commandPlayerSkill;
    OleDbCommand commandMain;
    DataSet dataSetMain;
    DataSet dataSetPlayerSkill;
```

Загрузка:

```
        // Таблица PlayerSkill
        connection.Open();
        adapter.SelectCommand = commandPlayerSkill;
        dataSetPlayerSkill = new DataSet();
        adapter.Fill(dataSetPlayerSkill);
        //adapter.Upd
        dataGridViewPlayerSkill.DataSource = dataSetPlayerSkill.Tables[0];
        adapter.Update(dataSetPlayerSkill);

        // Основная таблица
        tableNameMain = comboBox1.Text + " - " + comboBox2.Text;
        commandMain = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM [" + tableNameMain + "];", connection);
        adapter.SelectCommand = commandMain;
        dataSetMain = new DataSet();
        adapter.Fill(dataSetMain);
        dataGridViewMainBase.DataSource = dataSetMain.Tables[0];
        adapter.Update(dataSetMain);
        connection.Close();
```

Comment: Вы описали лишь SELECT, для сохранения опишите метод UPDATE в нужные ячейки. adapter.UpdateCommand = new OleDbCommand("умная команда на замену строки с указанием ячейки и внутренностей новой строки",connetion);

Comment: @xSx добавил эту строку(в теме обновил), компилятор более не выдает ошибки
Изменения сохраняются, если изменяется ячейка вручную(двойной клик по ячейки и ввод значения), но если ячейка изменяется программой( dataGridView2.Rows[0].Cells[j].Value = 2), то бд не сохраняет изменения

Comment: Если нужно изменить программно значения, зачем это делать в DataGridView? Внесите изменения в строки таблицы в датасете и не забудте вызвать метод AcceptChanges для подтверждения изменений. После этого можно вызывать метод Update. Проблема в данном случае в том, что при двойном щелчке происходит изменение датасета, а уже потом обновление текста таблицы. Вы же только изменяете текст, а данные в датасете не изменяются и команде Update нечего отправлять в базу данных.

Comment: @xSx появилась еще одна проблема, обновляется только первый запрос из всех, показал пример выше, заполняю значениями строку 1 в первом запросе, в строке 2 вторым запросом

Comment: Возможно или AcceptChanges(); надо вызвать или Validate(); посмотрю чуть позже. 
Так-же, когда вы меняете программно, можно было обновить сразу в базке и перегрузить табличку, как вариант.

Comment: @PleshkovIvan принудительно присваиваю DataSet значения из gridView, после чего делаю AcceptChanges и после Update(DataSet) - бд не сохраняется, код в вопросе обновил